# Display images on text console

Tags: arch-linux

I want to display image on the text console, like in Gentoo (penguins at top of the screen) while booting up. I tried `w3m`, but this won't display images on tty. So, how can I display image on this screen?

Comment: what do you mean by `teletype`?

Comment: He means tty, or probably console, like tty1

Comment: It is a kernel compile option

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display images without using X, on the console, you can use [`fbi`](https://www.nongnu.org/fbi-improved/).

It is most likely already packaged for your distribution.